# Passing row data to jquery function

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am iterating through a gridview using .each class and submitting the rowData of a gridview one by one to ajaxsubmit.

Everything is seems to be working fine. Except  var rowData I dont know how to pass it to ajaxsubmit. I have tried it using "#rowData" but it doesnt work.

```
 $("#submit").click(function () {
               var record;
               alert("starting");
               $("#<%=GridView3.ClientID%> input[id*='chkEmployee']:checked").each(function () {
                   var rowData = {
                       "privateID": $(this).closest('tr').find('.IDName').text(),
                       "Company": $(this).closest('tr').find('.FName').text(),
                       "Dun": $(this).closest('tr').find('.DName').text()
                   };
                       $("#rowData").ajaxsubmit(
                          "./employeeAdd"
                          , function () {
                              jInfo("data base been sumitted"
                                 }
                              );
                          });
                   });
```

Does anyone know how to pass the rowData to ajaxsubmit properly? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
var record;
alert("starting");
$("#<%=GridView3.ClientID%> input[id*='chkEmployee']:checked").each(function () {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Post.aspx/savePost",
    data: "{privateID:'" + $(this).closest('tr').find('.IDName').text() + "',Company:'" + $(this).closest('tr').find('.FName').text() + "',Dun:'" +$(this).closest('tr').find('.DName').text()}",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        if (data == undefined) {
            alert("Error : 219");
        }
        else {
            alert(data.d);
        }
    },
    error: function (data) {
        if (data == undefined) {
            alert("Error : 465");
        }
        else {
            alert("Error : 468 " + data.d);
        }
    }
});                   
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're referring to the ["ajaxSubmit"](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) JQuery plugin?  That's useful when you have an HTML form, but here you already have the post data -- just use [`JQuery post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/):

```
$.post("./employeeAdd", rowData, function() {
    jInfo("submitted");
});
```